# Add multiple text to a TextView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, parse-platform

I have created a TextView with similar details:

```
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tAge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tHeadline"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:gravity="center" 
            android:hint="Age"
                        android:textSize="18sp"

            android:textColor="#000" />
```

I would like to set text for multiple strings. such as

```
mUserAgeRetrieved.setText("Age:");

        mUserAgeRetrieved.setText(String.valueOf(objects.get(i).getInt("UserAge")));
```

Hence, the result of the above would be Age: (age that is generated from Parse).

Another Instance

```
mUserHeadlineRetrieved = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tHeadline);
mUserAgeRetrieved.setText("Headline:");

                mUserHeadlineRetrieved.setText(objects.get(i).get("Headline")
                        .toString());
```

Hence, the result of the above would be Headline: (Headline that is generated from Parse).
The problem I have is that It chose the last setText, and does not combined both of them.

Lets say I wanted to have one of them bold like Age: (bold) 25 (non-bold)

If you need any clarification, let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set both texts to a single string and then set it, like this:

```
    mUserAgeRetrieved.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>" + "Age:" + "</b>" + String.valueOf(objects.get(i).getInt("UserAge"))));
```

Comment: Ok check my edit, there you can set it, and put "age" in bold

Comment: Thank you for your edit. However, it seems to bold everything, where I would want only the first text to be bolded

Comment: Yes, I edited it again. I forgot to close the bold tag, now it should work.

Answer (score 4):

Of course it doesn't! setText sets new text.

The solution is very simple.

```
textView.setText("This: ");
textView.append("works");
```

textView should say "This: works"

Hope this helps,

good luck :)

Answer (score 2):

```
mUserAgeRetrieved.setText("Age: " + String.valueOf(objects.get(i).getInt("UserAge")));
```

or

```
mUserHeadlineRetrieved.setText("Headline: " + objects.get(i).get("Headline").toString());
```

You just need to use regular string concatenation.

Comment: Thank you for your response. How would I get just one of them to be bold? Like lets say I wanted Age (bold) actual age(non-bold)